# What’s the deal with Ms. Lint’s eye in The Tick?

Tags: the-tick

In *The Tick* there’s a super villain named Ms. Lint. In the first few episodes it was established that one of her eyes is made of glass - one popped out while fighting The Tick and she replaced it with another style later.

In the fourth and fifth episodes, “Party Crashers” and “Flying”, both of her eyes appear to be organic. Not only do they look symmetrical and natural, both eyes seem to track whoever she’s looking at.

I assume this isn’t a goof since it happened in more than one episode and more than one scene within episodes. What’s the explanation?

Comment: Oh sure, in reality it's because of [Bellisario's maxim](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim), that it's a TV show made on a budget by people in a hurry.

Comment: ^ TvTropes warning obliged, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the show's co-Executive Producer and writer, Susan Hurwitz Arneson (AKA [MurderCrow](https://www.reddit.com/user/smhurarn/comments/)), any discrepancies between Miss Lint's real (looking) eyes and the more dramatic eye designs she uses at other times can be ascribed to her wearing a glass eye that looks indistinguishable from her good eye.

> **Anyone notice Ms Lint's eye lost its damage in a number of scenes in S2?
> Was this explained in the plot (and I've simply forgotten) or did the VFX guys forget the CGI sometimes?**
>
> **smhurarn:** *Tick Co-EP here again. Lint has many fake eyes. Including one that is close to, but a bit off, from Yara's real eyes. It's the one Miss Lint puts on to look "normal" She also wore it in Season One when she crashed Walter's Birthday party.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/thetick/comments/co7tep/anyone_notice_ms_lints_eye_lost_its_damage_in_a/)</sup></sub>